# How to make jinja2 evaluate variable within a string?

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there a way that I can get variables defined within a string to be evaluated in jinja2? We can see in this definition of `alarm_list` below that `expr` is a string which contains other variables that are defined above such as `oea_env`, `oea_subsystem` etc. I want those variables to be evaluated so that the final product has an `expr` where those are filled in rather than leaving the `{{oea_env}}` etc behind.

```
{% set oea_env = "dev" %}
{% set oea_subsystem = "mysite" %}
{% set crit_high_rh = 85  %}

{% set alarm_list = [
  {
    'alert': 'No Temperature Readings',
    'expr': '(container_humidity_rh{oea_asset_id=~".*:service:1"} >= {{crit_high_rh}})'
  }] 
%}

{% macro generate_alerts(alarm_list) %}
  {% for alarm in alarm_list %}
  - alert: {{ alarm.alert }}
    expr: {{ alarm.expr }} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

# later in the code:
groups:
- name: 'my-prometheus-alerts'
  rules:
  {{generate_alerts(alarm_list) }}
```

I get:

```
groups:
- name: 'my-prometheus-alerts'
  rules:
  - alert: 'High humidity reading',
    expr: (container_humidity_rh{oea_asset_id=~".*:{{oea_env}}:{{oea_subsystem}}:service:1"} >= {{crit_high_rh}})
```

I *want*:

```
groups:
- name: 'my-prometheus-alerts'
  rules:
  - alert: 'High humidity reading',
    expr: (container_humidity_rh{oea_asset_id=~".*:dev:mysite:service:1"} >= 85)
```

If there was more uniformity in the expressions I was calling, I'd probably just make a macro with these variables as parameters to the macro, but since each of these expressions can be arbitrarily different, that isn't possible.

Thank you!

EDIT- this can be tested over at https://j2live.ttl255.com/, just plug in the code block and evaluate it. You'll see that it matches the behavior I'm seeing here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same need.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a double quote around the double brackets:

```
{% set alarm_list = [
  {
  'alert': 'No Temperature Readings',
  'expr': '(container_humidity_rh{oea_asset_id=~".*:service:1"} > "{{crit_high_rh}}")'
   }]
%}
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it does not work, it gets evaluated with the double quotes around the double brackets. Is there anything I need to do to force it to execute the string as code here: `{{ alarm.alert }}`? I read `{{ alarm.alert | safe }}` should do it, but I didn't see a difference there either.

Answer (score 0):

Use '~' to concatenate string and variable elements:

```
{% set some_var = "world" %}
{% set message = "Hello " ~ some_var ~ "!" %}
{{ message }}
```

results in "Hello world!"